# Ribbon. The value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj

Tags: c#, vsto, visual-studio-2019, ribbonx

I am adding Ribbon.
Instead of Ribbon, I am getting error.

**Error:**
The value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj

*at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Utilities.GetObjectData (IVsUIObject obj)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.ImageHelper.GetImageFromMoniker (ImageMoniker moniker, Size ImgSize, Int32 dpi, Nullable`1 backgroundColor)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.Themes.Office15Theme.GetFileMenuImage (Boolean hover, Boolean opened, Control control)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.Themes.OfficeTheme.GetFileMenuSize (Control control)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.RibbonView.InitializeComponent ()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.RibbonView.set_Site (ISite value)

at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add (IComponent component, String name)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd (IComponent component, String name)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent (Type componentType, String name)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance (Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance (Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Serialization.TypeResolutionModifications.VSTDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance (Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.Serialization.RibbonTypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad (IDesignerSerializationManager manager)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad (IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)

--- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad (IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted (Int32 fReload)*

**Description.**
I want to create an Excel Addin.
I created a project.
I am adding Ribbon.
An error is displayed instead of Ribon.

**Question.**
Why is there an error?
How to fix the error "The value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj"?

**Used.**

- Wni - 7x64;
- Visual Studio - 2019 Community.

**Picture1.**
[image]

**Picture2.**
[image]

**Picture3.**
[image]

---

### Update-1.

Opened a project in Visual Studio-2017 Community.
Ribbon opens.

**Question.**
Why won't Ribbon open in Visual Studio-2019 Community?

**Picture-4**
[image]

---

### Update-2

I made a right click - > I chose "Build".
Visual Studio has completed the "Build".
Visual Studio added a file to the Solution - `ExcelAddInTest_04_TemporaryKey.pfx`.
I added a Ribbon.
Result: Error.

The value cannot be undefined. Parameter name: obj

*in Microsoft. Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Utilities.GetObjectData(IVsUIObject obj)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.ImageHelper.GetImageFromMoniker(ImageMoniker moniker, Size ImgSize, Int32 dpi, Nullable`1 backgroundColor)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.Themes.Office15Theme.GetFileMenuImage(Boolean hover, Boolean opened, Control control)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.Themes.OfficeTheme.GetFileMenuSize(Control control)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.RibbonView.InitializeComponent()
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.RibbonView.set_Site(ISite value)
in System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Serialization.TypeResolutionModifications.VSTDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.Serialization.RibbonTypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of the stack trace from the previous location where the exception occurred ---
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
in Microsoft. VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)*

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

---

### Update-3.

I moved to Visual Studio-2017.
I created an add-on (project-1).
I added a Ribbon.
Ribbon is displayed.

I moved to Visual Studio-2019.
I opened a previously created add-in (project-1).
I opened the Ribbon.
Ribbon is not displayed. I get an error.
I started debugging (F5).
I opened an Excel file.

**Result:** Ribbon is displayed in Excel.

Comment: What is the difference between VS2017 and VS2019? Do you have both installed on the same machine? Did you try to build the add-in before adding a ribbon designer?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev **1.** `What is the difference between VS2017 and VS2019?` I don't understand your question. I had VS-2017 installed. After that I installed VS-2019. I did not uninstall VS-2017.
**2.** `Do you have both installed on the same machine?`. Yes. **3.** `Did you try to build the add-in before adding a ribbon designer?`. How to understand `create an add-in before adding a ribbon designer`? For Excel, I haven't done add-ins before. I've tried making add-ins for MSProject. Everything worked. Only I do not remember in which VS I made add-ins for MSProject.

Comment: Try to build the add-in (right-click on the project and choose `Build`) before adding aby ribbon designers.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Does not work. See `Update-2`.